# How to create a plugin with Service Builder by Liferay Maven?

Tags: java, maven, liferay

I'm using Liferay 6.2.0
I add remote repository for archetype from http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/liferay/maven/archetypes/

I can create a portlet in it, but I want create a Service Builder the option of the plugin reference is empty, so it can't create the service.xml

### I've tried to create manually the service.xml and build it with maven but the error message say me that the plugin is not found!

I've tried the tutorial advised me by Rushikesh Thakkar from http://www.cignex.com/articles/building-liferay-service-using-maven-sdk
but eclipse doesn't get me the option to select the plugin to create a service builder.

I've create manually service.xml and I've tried to build it but there is an error:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'liferay' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/matteo/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Comment: There are plenty of articles for this requirement (e.g. http://www.cignex.com/articles/building-liferay-service-using-maven-sdk). You need to do enough research/googling before posting to StackOverflow.

Comment: Enough research will give the answer :) and we want to find the answer. So some research and some attempt is required. Anyways did you try making use of the maven error: `[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.` Also if possible try to provide your `service.xml`

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? It would be great if you would share the info here! I'm havingthe same issue.

Comment: @RushikeshThakkar That guide says at the bottom `"I assume that the valid service.xml file is already exist"`. I and perhaps other newbies have no idea what that file is, it would help if there was a little more extensive documentation on the matter, like a requirements list before using guides in the beginning, such as `I assume you know what services is, if not check _here_`. That'd be great and would simplify research a lot. A StackOverflow Q&A never harms. If this would be solved it would have helped me a lot.

Comment: @Nenotlep,
The reason myself and Prakash (see his comment) suggested doing some research was in the best interest of the poster and also for stackoverflow. However, since you think there is not enough documentation on this topic, I am posting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This error means: when you run 'mvn liferay:build-service', Maven fails to understand what "liferay" means here. It could be because Maven was not able to find out Liferay portlet plugin in either your local repo or the remote repo (if you've configured any). Most of the times this would happen if the archetype was not chosen correctly, or there were errors when the Portlet was created.

Here are some links that describe how to use Maven to build your portlet:

1. Liferay documentation: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/developing-plugins-using-maven-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-02--2
2. Blog post explaining the same, but simple and straightforward: http://michi-path.blogspot.com.au/2013/06/liferay-with-maven-deploying-simple.html

Service builder is a Liferay feature to build back-end for your portlets. Liferay has very good documentation available on how Service Builder. It begins with writing service.xml file. Have a look at the below links to understand it better:

1. Liferay documentation on service builder: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/what-is-service-builder-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-04--2
2. Blog post explaining how to build a maven portlet having service.xml: http://michi-path.blogspot.com.au/2013/06/liferay-with-maven-service-builder.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hi @Mouser, it is not possible for me post an entire tutorial (or two - in this case) for an answer which was not required at first place. Hope you will understand.

Comment: As Mouser mentioned before. its bad Idea to post links as answear. the links don't work any more.